# How to get an optimal solution using JuMP in julia?

Tags: julia, gurobi, julia-jump

I am using the JuMP package in julia with gurobi, and I can't seem to find any information online about how to print out an optimal solution. I can get the optimal objective value, but can't seem to find info on how to get an optimal solution. I tried solution_summary, but that gave me an error

Comment: Here's the documentation https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/tutorials/getting_started/getting_started_with_JuMP/

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `value(varname)` such as:

```
m = Model(Gurobi.Optimizer);
@variable(m, x[1:2] >= 0)
@constraint(m, [1 2;3 4] * x .<= [10,20])
@objective(m, Max, [1,2]' * x )
optimize!(m)
```

and now:

```
julia> value.(x)
2-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.0
 5.0
```

Note that even if the model is MILP, the `value` will be always `Float64` so usually you end up wanting to round it in some way or other.